# G'dolim or Rabbis Owning Pets

Tags: history, rabbis, agriculture, animals

Are there any *[g'dolim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gadol)* (or rabbis of major influence) - past or present - who are known to have owned pets/kept animals for non-agricultural purposes?

Comment: Were King David's dogs pets or work animals?  (For evidence that he had dogs, see Shabbat 30b.)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30111

Comment: https://seforimblog.com/2020/06/pets-on-shabbat-rabbi-morenu-and-epidemics/ this cites that a R Nachun Zeev, R Dessler's father-in-law, had a pet dog

Answer (score 8):

Reb Avrohom Gurwitz had a cat when I was in Gateshead

Comment: Did he have it as a classical pet or as a mouse removal device?

Answer (score 7):

There is always this picture of Rav Lopian

[ר' אל'ע איז מיט ג-ט](http://theantitzemach.blogspot.com/2010/09/blog-post.html)

Comment: And the famous comment, "how do we know he was putting the saucer out for the cat, maybe the photo caught him as he was taking it away ..."

Comment: I'm guessing if that were really his cat it would be documented somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [Tshuva of the Ya'avetz 17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43089&pgnum=70) <sup>(1)</sup> where he says it is forbidden for a woman to have a dog as a pet, 2 dogs for a man, and to play with a dog is "Moshav Letsim" for everybody. One can use a dog as a guard dog if he keeps it on a leash. and keeps them  to a minimum.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> ואפילו מאן דפליג בכופרים לא שרי טפי מחד לנטורי ביתא לנטורי ביתא בלחוד דהכי מוכח מהא דגר שנפלו לו בירושה שאין מחייבין אותו למכור כי אם על יד ועל כרחך בכופרים איירי דלא מזקי דאי לאו הכי ודאי שאסור לקיימן בביתו אפילו זמן מועט ואפילו אחד לא אם אינו קשור ואפילו הכי לא שרי אלא במי שנפלו לו בירושה להשהותן רק כדי למוכרן מעט מעט שלא יפסיד הרבה. מיהא לגדלן אצלו מכל מקום אסור...דסלקא דעתך אמינא לארמלתא שרי טפי דלא בעיא ליה לטיול אלא לשמור הבית מאריא וגנבי אורחא בהכי לריבויי משום נטירוטא דביתא קמ"ל דאפילו הכי אסור משום חשדא ואין צריך לומר שאסור לנשים בעלמא שאין מגדלות אותו אלא לשעשוע בלבד...וגם משום מושב ליצים אסור לשחור עמהם... ‏

Comment: Interesting. Do we know of _g'dolim_ who have had chained guard dogs? Was Rav Ya'akov Emden dealing with dogs that were more dangerous than the ones commonly kept as pets? He seems to be speaking about much more serious danger than most pet owners ever experience, doesn't he?

Comment: Regarding 1), he refers to the well-known _sakana_ involved in owning dogs, which leads to the condition that they be chained up under all circumstances. This _sakana_ is not well-known to me with regard to the dogs that are currently usually maintained as pets.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the gemoroh in baba kamma  says yours allowed to have a dog a cat and a porcupine as a pet(maybe missing one more) because they keep the house clean by eating all the bones and stuff left over. This is regarding small dogs, big dogs are meant to be outside of the main city for protection.

Comment: @dhoweedyaagov most people don't keep pets for cleanliness, they have a vacuum for that

Comment: @shmuel brin that doesn't matter, gemoroh says your allowed to, therefore your allowed to keep them.

Comment: This seems like a comment.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin  I am sorry I edited the answer because it was almost flaged and qualified as comment. In way to mak it more explicit, I wrote a part of the Shut and I make a little tikun concerning 1 dog as pet for a man. If you think that it is not right, don't worry and cancel my edit.

Answer (score 5):

There's a story here about the Zhviller Rebbe keeping pet cats: [The Rebbe's Cats.](http://www.jewishspirit.com/Journal/tales_1.html)

Comment: Shivaram, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for this very on-point reference! I hope you'll look around and find other material here that animates you, perhaps including our 76 other [tag:animals] questions.

Answer (score 4):

I know of a Rosh Yeshiva in South Africa that kept dogs for protection.

Comment: Did he personally ever deal with the dogs or did his 'help' handle that?

Comment: He personally fed them at times, and often petted them.

Answer (score 3):

My Chabad Rabbi told me that the Lubavitcher Rebbe bought his wife a dog to cheer her up because she was sad that she couldn't have a baby.

Comment: See Joseph Telushkin's Rebbe book, page 366 for an interesting story between Rebbetzin Chaya Mushka and a dog.

Answer (score 2):

The last Lubavitcher Rebbe had a German Shepherd guard dog. [Source.](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/4273415/jewish/They-Are-All-Our-Children.htm)

Answer (score 0):

From the Gemara in Chullin 112 it seems that Shmuel had a dog and would throw prohibited items to it to eat.

שמואל שדי ליה לכלביה
Shmuel would throw to his dog.

Answer (score -3):

The Avos had sheep, camels, oxen and not all of it was for agricultural purposes.

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: Can you cite one or two?

Comment: You see that Yaakov sent Aisav a whole slew of animals as a gift. This gift included many non kosher animals. They also used donkeys for transportation.

Comment: How do we know that the non-kosher animals were not for agricultural purposes?

Comment: How do you know he kept Kosher? ;-P

Comment: @SethJ - Kept or no kept, some animals are _t'horim_ and some are _t'me'im_, as differentiated by _Noach_. The term we use in modern times for some reason to refer to the _tahor_ ones is "kosher". That, and you were joking so I'll stop now.

Comment: @WAF I don't know about t'me'im but some were definitely einam t'horim.

Comment: "not agricultural" does not equal "pets".